# Why does array keep Duplicate Data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, unit-testing

While working with PHP ,handling connection's with Database (MySQL)

```
$result = mysql_query('select * from products');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

And yesterday founded out that array `$row` had Duplicate data within.

First you have Data's selected from database arranged in Indexes like : `$row[0] = ID;` than you also could find `$row['ID'] = ID.`

So is this only a feature of the Framework ,which copies data Virtually or are these Data's stored twice in array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight [from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a
>   numeric array, or both

The prototype of the function says that

```
array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )
```

meaning that it returns both arrays by default - that is - duplicating the info

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer ,so using both Keys and Indexes is a Memory Leak ,right?

Comment: No, it just uses more memory - a memory leak would be if that memory would remain used, not being freed, but I assume it is freed when your $row goes out of scope

Answer (score 2):

To get only one value set, you need to pass a second parameter to mysql_fetch_array.
either "MYSQL_ASSOC" to get an associative array, or "MYSQL_NUM" to get a normal array.
Example:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, 'MYSQL_ASSOC')
```

This will return:

```
$row['id']
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both. Please see: [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Answer (score 0):

Each row in `$result` has an index, a name and a value. You can look up a row's value by either index or name.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation for `mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Default setting is to fetch an array with both numeric and associative array. See PHP manual to change that.